# What does "s" do as a format specifier?

Tags: c#, .net, string-formatting

Is the `":s"` in this expression `string.format("{0:s}", "hello world")` just mean that the variable is a string?  I'm just not sure why anyone would ever do this.

I found this in code and would like to remove the `":s"` but want to be sure that I'm not altering behavior.

Comment: As to the why: in some other languages, e.g. C and Java, string formats are more like `%s` for strings, `%d` for numbers, etc. Someone familiar with that might naturally try to use `{0:s}` (instead of `{0}`) for a string.

Comment: @TimS. Good point.  That must be what happened.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the [Sortable specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#Sortable) for the Standard Date And Time Format Strings

In your case (Printing a string) I think it has no effect on the output

The specifier acts on DateTime value converting it to a display format suitable for sorting.
For example calling this code

```
 string result = string.Format("-{0:s}-", DateTime.Now);
 Console.WriteLine(result)
```

will print

```
2013-09-04T19:27:56
```

Comment: Not allowed to accept your answer for another 9 minutes, so I will shortly.  Thank you!  Hilarious that this is being used on urls and other non-date values.

Comment: More from MSDN documentation: `The SortableDateTimePattern property defines the culture-specific format of date strings that are returned by calls to the DateTime.ToString and DateTimeOffset.ToString methods and by composite format strings that are supplied the "s" standard format string.`